# Setting innerHTML in a webview replaces the entire document instead of just the element

Tags: javascript, android, dom, webview, scaloid

Note: This is scaloid, so the syntax is a bit different from Java, but all the classes are the usual Android classes from Java.

I'm initializing a webview using:

```
webView.settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true)
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient)
```

and then I call

```
val jsUrl = "javascript:document.getElementById('" + getTagId(word) + "').innerHTML = '" + guess + "'"
webView.loadUrl(jsUrl)
```

where `getTagId(word)` is an existing ID (I've debugged this) and `guess` is a short string like `"abc"`.

It works perfectly in my desktop browser, but in the webview it replaces the entire document instead of just replacing the element.

I've tried to debug and make sure that the element is actually found by replacing the call with

```
"javascript:alert(document.getElementById('" + getTagId(word) + "').innerHTML)"
```

and it shows an alert with the right content! Only the replacement goes wrong.

This bug is driving me crazy :-( What am I missing?

P.S. I'm working on this open-source project: https://github.com/ilyakogan/gluckentext

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why this didn't work, but I ended up adding a JS function and calling it from the native Android code, instead of calling `getElementById` directly from the native code.

I added this to the HTML:

```
<script>
    function markSolved(id) { document.getElementById(id).className='solved'; }
</script>
```

and then wrote this in the native code (Scala in my case, Java in the general case):

```
val jsUrl = "javascript:markSolved(" + getTagId(answeredWord) + ")"
webView.loadUrl(jsUrl)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just wrap custom Js code in module:

```
view.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){document.getElementById('uname').value = 'test';})()");
```

Works for me